# Existing cloud function fails to deploy after move to nodejs14

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I've got an existing cloud function that has been running fine on node 10 for some time.
As part of some maintenance we upgraded it to node 14 and it's failing to deploy now with the following error.

> Function failed on loading user code. This is likely due to a bug in the user code. Error message: . Please visit https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting for in-depth troubleshooting documentation.

The docs linked suggest that this is caused by a bad entry point, but the entry point for this code hasn't changed since it was running smoothly on node 10.

I've checked the logs and the build looks like it goes fine and there's no messages or errors being thrown by the user code.

The entry point is exported from a file `src/index.js` as

```
function proxy() { ... }

module.exports = { proxy };
```

To verify, I even created a little dummy script to verify my code can load from that entry point

```
// test.js
const { proxy } = require('./src');

const req = {
    get: () => 'Bearer test',
    originalUrl: '/test',
};
const res = {
    set: console.log,
    status(...args) {
        console.log(...args);
        return this;
    },
    send: console.log,
};

proxy(req, res).catch(console.error);
```

Running `node test.js` I see the function execute.

Here's relevant parts of the `package.json`

```
{
    "name": "proxy-app",
    "main": "src/index.js",
    "engines": {
        "node": ">=14.0.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": "mocha spec/**/*.js",
    },
    "devDependencies": {
    ...
    },
    "dependencies": {
    ...
    },
  ...
}
```

Here's the command I used to deploy:

```
gcloud functions deploy proxy --service-account=${SERVICE_ACCOUNT} \
 --allow-unauthenticated  --region=${REGION} --project=${GCLOUD_PROJECT} \
 --trigger-http --runtime=nodejs14 \
 --update-env-vars=DATASTORE_PROJECT_ID=${GCLOUD_PROJECT}
```

**UPDATE** This is only happening in our staging environment, not production, so seems like it must be a configuration or permissions issue, but I'm still stumped as to what it is.

Comment: Do you have more inputs in cloud logging?

Comment: nothing relevant, just the logs of the build, but they are all successful. The code itself doesn't seem to run at all, i can see not logs from the code launching